# the npm debug still show Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@utils/time/time' after replace the path

Tags: node.js, typescript

when I using this `npm run start` command to start the project, shows error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/js-wheel/dist/index.js 6:0-58
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@auth/extension/AuthHandler' in '/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/ai-web/node_modules/js-wheel/dist'

ERROR in ./node_modules/js-wheel/dist/index.js 7:0-49
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@utils/graphic/RdColor' in '/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/ai-web/node_modules/js-wheel/dist'

ERROR in ./node_modules/js-wheel/dist/index.js 8:0-44
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@utils/file/RdFile' in '/Users/John/source/reddwarf/frontend/ai-web/node_modules/js-wheel/dist'
```

I have already replaced the `js-wheel` relative path, and run npm update command to refresh the dependencies. this is the index.js file in `./node_modules/js-wheel/dist` looks like right now:

```
import { ResponseHandler } from "./src/net/rest/ResponseHandler";
import { RequestHandler } from "./src/net/rest/RequestHandler";
import { WheelGlobal } from "./src/model/immutable/WheelGlobal";
import { TimeUtils } from "./src/utils/time/time";
import { ResponseCode } from "./src/net/rest/ResponseCode";
import { AuthHandler } from "./src/auth/extension/AuthHandler";
import { RdColor } from "./src/utils/graphic/RdColor";
import { RdFile } from "./src/utils/file/RdFile";
export { ResponseHandler, RequestHandler, WheelGlobal, TimeUtils, ResponseCode, AuthHandler, RdColor, RdFile };
```

why still show this error? what should I do to fixed this issue? I also tried to clear the cache `npm cache clean --force` and reinstall the dependencies using `npm install`, still could not work. This is the js-wheel dependencies:

```
"js-wheel": "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel.git",
```

the `npm run build` command works fine. this is the package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ai-web",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@ant-design/icons": "^5.0.1",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/event-source-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "@types/hashmap": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "antd": "^5.4.2",
    "axios": "^1.3.4",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "event-source-polyfill": "^1.0.31",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.7.0",
    "hashmap": "^2.4.0",
    "idb": "^7.1.1",
    "js-wheel": "https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel.git",
    "query-string": "8.1.0",
    "rd-component": "0.1.23",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-markdown": "^8.0.5",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.0",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "tslib": "^2.5.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-app-rewired start",
    "build": "react-app-rewired build",
    "test": "react-app-rewired test",
    "eject": "react-app-rewired eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-syntax-highlighter": "^15.5.6",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.6.0",
    "browser-sync": "^2.29.1",
    "customize-cra": "^1.0.0",
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-cli": "^2.3.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^6.0.0-alpha.1",
    "react-app-rewired": "^2.2.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `js-wheel`? That doesn't seem to be the npm package of the same name. Those module resolution errors look like they're coming from code that wasn't built correctly, meaning the js-wheel package didn't transpile some import aliases or something away.

Comment: this is the public lib across all project. I did not upload it to npm repo. I am sure the alias was transformed successfully.

Comment: Ah, I see you changed that a couple of commits ago. Does using `git+https://github.com/jiangxiaoqiang/js-wheel.git#b19a066` (the most recent commit sha) get it updated correctly?

Comment: I think the url was not the issue because I can view the newest replaced path file in the local node_modules folder.

Comment: Ah. Then when you reinstalled it, did you also `rm -rf node_modules` first, or at least `rm -rf node_modules/.cache`? There definitely seems to be a cached copy of the previous version somewhere.

Comment: I publish the package to npm repo. I have take too much time so solve this issue.